# Question regarding surjectivity of the resolvent of a bounded linear operator at the boundary of its resolvent set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am reading this theorem and cannot understand the last inequality:

> Theorem 2. Let $M : X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear operator, $\lambda$ a boundary point of the spectrum of $M$, $\sigma(M)$. Then the range of $\lambda - M$ is not all of $X$.
>
> Proof: Since $\lambda$ is assumed to be a boundary point of $\sigma(M)$, it is the limit of a sequence $\lambda_n$ in the resolvent set of $M$, $\rho(M)$. According to corollary 3' of theorem 3 in chapter 17, the norm of the resolvent is $\geq$ the reciprocal of the distance to some point of the spectrum: $$|(\zeta-M)^{-1}|\geq|\zeta-\lambda|^{-1}.$$
>
> This implies that there is a $u$, depending on $\zeta$, such that $(\zeta - M)^{-1}u = x$ is large compared to $u$: $$(\zeta - M)x = u,\ \ \ |x|> \frac{1}{2|\zeta-\lambda|}|u|.$$

I don't understand how to obtain the inequality $|x|> \frac{1}{2|\zeta-\lambda|}|u|$. Backtracking, we can say $$|(\zeta-M)^{-1}||u|\geq\frac{1}{|\zeta-\lambda|}|u|> \frac{1}{2|\zeta-\lambda|}|u|.$$ But from boundedness, I only know: $$|x|\leq|(\zeta-M)^{-1}||u|,\ \ \ |u|\leq|(\zeta-M)||x|.$$ I also tried to see if $|(\zeta-M)|$ is the inverse of $|(\zeta-M)^{-1}|$, but I didn't manage that either. If I had to guess, the factor of $1/2$ is actually just an arbitrary value between $0$ and $1$.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: In case it's helpful, this is Chapter 20, page 227-228 of Peter D. Lax "Functional Analysis".

Comment: If $\|A\|\ge C>0,$ then for any $0<D<C$ there exists $u\neq 0$ such that $\|Au\|>D\|u\|.$ In particular this holds for $D={1\over 2}C.$